# How to check existing email id in mysql database using java

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc

I want check if the email id entered by user is already available in database.

I used following script:

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
              $(".email").change(function(){
                  var email = $(this).val();
                  if(email.length >= 3){
                      $(".status").html("<img src='images/loading.gif'><font color=gray> Checking availability...</font>");
                       $.ajax({
                          type: "POST",
                          url: "checkemail.do",
                          data: "email="+ email,
                          success: function(msg){

                              $(".status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){

                                  $(".status").html(msg);
    <input id="emailsignup" name="emailid" type="text"
                                placeholder="mysupermail@mail.com" />
                                <input type="text" class="email" />
                            &nbsp;
                            <span class="status"></span>
                        </p>
                              });
                          }
                      }); 
                  }
                  else{

                      $(".status").html("<font color=red>Username should be <b>3</b> character long.</font>");
                  }

              });
          });
        </script>







<label for="emailsignup" class="youmail">
                                Your email
                            </label>
                            <input id="emailsignup" name="emailid" type="text"
                                placeholder="mysupermail@mail.com" />
                                <input type="text" class="email" />
                            &nbsp;
                            <span class="status"></span>
```

---

method inside controller class.Here i am trying to get emailid from request- and calling the service method and further the model class.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/checkemail.do")
public String checkEmail(HttpServletRequest req){
  String emailid= req.getParameter("emailid");
    service.checkemail(emailid);
    return "email";

}
```

Comment: Where is the java code part?

Comment: Here I see only JavaScript. Where is Java indeed?

Comment: @YassinHajaj   i have added java code also

Comment: @Klever now you can see java code :)

Comment: Do you want a link to "How to use MySQL with Java" ? I'm not sure what is the problem.

Comment: @AJAYPRAKASHDUBEY ok, going further, what `service.checkemail(emailid);` method does? Its code?

Comment: @Klever that method  is calling model layer which is interacting with mysql database to check email. but the problem is that controller class method is not called on change.

Comment: `$(".uname").change(function(){` but at the same time `<input type="text" class="email" />`. Either the class is wrong, or you are yet to give us related piece of code.

Comment: @bezmax Thanks for pointing. I have changed it as you can see in the code but still it is not working......

Comment: Try opening the developer console of whatever browser you use, and check the error logs.